# Fixing grub-efi-amd64-signed error

Tags: 20.04, grub2, debconf

`apt upgrade` on Ubuntu 22.04 failed with an error from grub-efi-amd64-signed.

```
mount: /var/lib/grub/esp: special device /dev/sda15 does not exist
```

/dev/sda15 does not and has never existed on this system.

```
$ debconf-get-selections | grep grub-pc
grub-pc grub-efi/install_devices    multiselect /dev/sda15
grub-pc grub-pc/install_devices multiselect /dev/disk/by-id/ata-[id1], /dev/disk/by-id/ata-[id2]
grub-pc grub-pc/install_devices_empty   boolean false
```

I removed the /dev/sda15 line from debconf (purged settings, re-added the two good lines, and removed `/var/cache/debconf`).

Now, when I run `apt upgrade`, I see a grub popup:

> You chose not to install GRUB to any devices. If you continue, the boot loader may not be properly configured, and when this computer next starts up it will use whatever was previously configured. If there is an earlier version of GRUB 2 in the EFI system partition, it may be unable to load modules or handle the current configuration file.
>
> If you are already using a different boot loader and want to carry on doing so, or if this is a special environment where you do not need a boot loader, then you should continue anyway. Otherwise, you should install GRUB somewhere.
>
> Continue without installing GRUB?

I'm not sure what to do here and I'm worried that my server will end up unbootable if I get it wrong.

Comment: Grub-pc is for BIOS boot and grub-efi-amd64 is for UEFI boot. You typically do not want to mix them. The only real difference between a BIOS install and an UEFI install of Ubuntu is the version of grub. If you have an UEFI system generally better to user UEFI. But you then should use gpt partitioning & must have an ESP - efi system partition. So is install UEFI or BIOS? And signed would mean you turned on UEFI Secure boot and then cannot boot in BIOS mode. Technically there are two versions of grub-efi-amd64, one signed for Secure boot and one not signed.